# Pasar CASE como parámetro

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una función que recibe parámetros y devuelve un resultado, de la siguiente manera funciona bien:

```
DECLARE @var varchar (10)
EXEC @var = GetLinea '','','', '' , ''
SELECT @var
```

Pero cuando quiero rellenar los valores que envío por parámetro con un `CASE` me tira error:

```
DECLARE @var varchar (10)
EXEC @var = GetLinea '', CASE WHEN '11' = '11' THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END ,'', '' , ''
SELECT @var
```

El error que aparece es:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Como si estuviese usando mal el `CASE`.

El código que pase es a modo prueba, debo ejecutar la función en una vista.

Este es el caso verdadero, los otros son pruebas que utilice

```
SELECT 
IdOferta, 
Location,
PRO, 
Toneladas, 
Espesor, 
Ancho, 


CASE WHEN Location<>''
        THEN 'MP_' + location
     WHEN CHARINDEX('PREPI', clase_desc)>0 Or CHARINDEX('CINCA', clase_desc)>0
        THEN 'REV_CA'
     ELSE 
        GetLinea
             parametro1,
             CASE WHEN Null = parametro2 THEN '' ELSE parametro2 END,
             CASE WHEN Null = parametro3 THEN '' ELSE parametro3 END,
             CASE WHEN Null = parametro4 THEN '' ELSE parametro4 END,
             parametro5
     END
AS Linea_Final
```

Comment: Creo que tu mejor opcion es usar un procedimiento almacenado en lugar de una vista

Comment: @JesusRodríguez Ahi estoy viendo de usarlo como SP, pero tendría que usar el declare y set antes del select y no me reconoce las variables

Comment: Amplie la respuesta para en caso de que lo consideres usar como procedimiento almacenado

Comment: @JesusRodríguez Vi la respuesta, el problema es que hay un SELECT, no me deja usar el SET PARAMETRO1 = case when VAL1 = '11'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END despues del SELECT y al usarlo antes no obtengo el valor que iría en val1

Comment: Puedes poner ese codigo del select en la pregunta porfavor

Comment: @JesusRodríguez Ahi lo agregue, faltarian los FROM no mas que no cambia nada

Comment: Actualice la respuesta de acuerdo a tu ultima edicion

Comment: @JesusRodríguez Gracias Jesus, pero eso no funciona, la variable VAL1 que aparece en tu respuesta es un valor que toma dentro del select por lo tanto si lo pongo como vos indicas aparece el mensaje que no reconoce la variable

Comment: El procedimiento es un prototipo que tu puedes modificar de acuerdo a tus necesidades no necesariamente tienes que usarlo de esa forma, asumo que GetLinea es un procedimiento almacenado y quieres usar los parametros provenientes de tu select cierto? y parametrox equivale a IdOferta, Location o etc ?

Comment: Adicionalmente que es lo que hace GetLinea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar una variable intermedia como parametro, 
ya que exec no acepta expresiones como parametro:

```
DECLARE @var varchar (10),
     @parametro varchar(10) =  (case when '11' = '11'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END)
EXEC @var = GetLinea_Nodo_Material '', @parametro ,'', '' , ''
SELECT @var
```

En el caso de una vista puedes usar:

```
 if '11' = '11'
    begin
        EXEC GetLinea_Nodo_Material '', 'SI' ,'', '' , ''
    end
    else
    begin
        EXEC GetLinea_Nodo_Material '', 'SI NO' ,'', '' , ''
    end
```

**Nota** De acuerdo a tu condicion de '11' = '11' siempre va a entrar al caso de si

En modo de procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedimiento
(
@VARIABLE VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT,
@VAL1 INT,  
@VAL2 INT,
@VAL3 INT,
@VAL4 INT,
@VAL5 INT
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PARAMETRO1 VARCHAR(10),
        @PARAMETRO2 VARCHAR(10),
        @PARAMETRO3 VARCHAR(10),
        @PARAMETRO4 VARCHAR(10),
        @PARAMETRO5 VARCHAR(10)


 SET @PARAMETRO1 = case when @VAL1 = '11'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END
 SET @PARAMETRO2 = (case when @VAL2 = '12'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END)
 SET @PARAMETRO3 = (case when @VAL3 = '13'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END)
 SET @PARAMETRO4 = (case when @VAL4 = '14'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END)
 SET @PARAMETRO5 = (case when @VAL5 = '15'  THEN 'SI' ELSE 'SI NO' END)

EXEC @VARIABLE = GetLinea_Nodo_Material @PARAMETRO1, @PARAMETRO2 ,@PARAMETRO3, @PARAMETRO4 , @PARAMETRO5
SELECT @VARIABLE

SELECT 
IdOferta, 
Location,
PRO, 
Toneladas, 
Espesor, 
Ancho, 


CASE WHEN Location<>''
        THEN 'MP_' + location
     WHEN CHARINDEX('PREPI', clase_desc)>0 Or CHARINDEX('CINCA', clase_desc)>0
        THEN 'REV_CA'
     ELSE 
        @VARIABLE
     END
AS Linea_Final
END
--FROM TU TABLA?
```

**Nota** Aqui ya depende de que realmente necesites manejar como parametros puedes ajustar, agregar o quitar a tu necesidad
**Nota2** no se si el select proviene de una tabla o de variables de otro sitio pero quedaria algo asi en esa forma

Saludos

Comment: El problema es que es una vista entonces no me deja declarar variables

Comment: En tu pregunta mencionas un snipset de codigo en el cual comentas que te funciona y en este esta declarada una variable por lo que se asumio que no estaba la restriccion de una vista, en el caso de la vista tendras que usar sentencias if para definir el parametro con la que se ejecutara el sp, Saludos

Comment: Si perdón, ahí edite la pregunta, esa parte la estaba probando en otro lado porque quería verificar que devuelva el resultado correcto. No es un SP, es una vista, se puede usar IF en la vista?

Comment: Tu vista quedaria como lo menciono en la segunda opcion, lo unico que me queda duda es sobre tu condicion para elegir caso que se ejecutara

Comment: La condición la puse para probar, ya que en realidad es una query mas grande donde usa variables, quería achicar el fragmento de código para probar por eso puse una condición cualquiera. El problema es que todos los parámetros tienen una condición. No se enviar ningún tipo de condición en parámetros no?. Ahora edito la pregunta y pongo todo entero

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás intentando validar los parámetros de entrada de tu función `GetLinea` *antes* de pasarlos a la función.

En todo caso, puedes hacer esa validación adentro de la función `GetLinea`:

```
create function GetLinea (
    @par1 varchar(30) = null,
    @par2 varchar(30) = null,
    @par3 varchar(30) = null,
    @par4 varchar(30) = null,
    @par5 varchar(30) = null
)
returns varchar(100)
begin
    declare @resultado varchar(100);

    ...

    set @par1 = isnull(@par1, '');
    set @par2 = isnull(@par2, '');
    set @par3 = case when @par3 is null then '' else @par3 end;
    set @par4 = case when isnull(@par4, '') = 'X' then 'SI' else 'NO' end;
    set @par5 = case when isnull(@par5, 'X') = 'X' then 'Y' else 'Z' end;

    ...

    return @resultado;
end;
```

De esta manera desde la vista simplemente utilizas la función directamente sin importar los valores que le pases:

```
SELECT 
    IdOferta, 
    Location,
    PRO, 
    Toneladas, 
    Espesor, 
    Ancho, 
    CASE
    WHEN Location<>'' THEN
        'MP_' + location
    WHEN CHARINDEX('PREPI', clase_desc)>0 Or CHARINDEX('CINCA', clase_desc)>0 THEN
        'REV_CA'
    ELSE 
        GetLinea (
            parametro1,
            parametro2,
            parametro3,
            parametro4,
            parametro5
        )
    END AS Linea_Final
```